# How do I chance the order of granularities in CleverMaps project?

Tags: datamodel, clevermaps

I'm setting up a CleverMaps project and I cannot find out why the granularities are ordered the way they are. In the data model I connected the data in the right order, but in the menu they don't appear the way I want. I'm adding the screenshots of the data model and the granularity menu to explain my problem. Any idea would be helpful!

[Granularities menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uMM7.png)
[Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btbc9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Only way how to order granularities by you is to set different maximal zooms in VectorTile dataset. You can only do it in metadata file. There is no way to do it on UI yet.

For example the most detail dataset:

> "zoom": {
> "min": 8,
> "optimal": 10,
> "max": 15
> }

next dataset:

> "zoom": {
> "min": 8,
> "optimal": 10,
> "max": 14
> }